# Apache 2 Webserver on Raspbian not loading any Images

Tags: apache2

I have a Pi running an Apache Webserver on only my local Network.
The Index.php File has only a single line of code:

`<img src="p.jpg" alt="not loading">`

the image is in the same folder as the PHP file.

yet when I connect to the website from my computer (or any other device) the pictures only show the alt message.

These are the permissions:

[image: permissions]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your index.php file also needs to be able to [execute](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/unix/unix-file-permission.htm) the image.  Is there any reason to lock the image down so only its owner (or root) can access it?  I would think the standard 644 (owner can do anything, group user can read/execute, and everyone else can read/execute) should be fine.

```
chmod 644 p.jpg
```

If there is a reason to lock down the image so heavily, you will at least need execution permission.  In this case, use `chmod 700 p.jpg` instead.

Comment: thank you so much. I have been playing around with Permissions for 4 hours now and somehow only this has worked eventhough I also gave permission to execute before. I am almost crying because it has been so annoying.